# Copying / applying styles by keyboard shortcut in Open Office - similar to Format Paintbrush?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, formatting, openoffice, shortcuts, openoffice-writer

I would like to achieve a similar effect of using the *Format Paintbrush* without having to actually press the button each time.

1. Is it possible to select the **Format Paintbrush** Tool by **keyboard shortcut**?
2. Could it be solved with a **macro** that copies the selected text or object's style and another one that applies it to another object?

Comment: You should be able to assign a macro to `Format Paintbrush` tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the shortcut from Tools > Customize and then select keyboard tab.. Then in the categories select the Edit category and then select the format paintbrush function.. Assign your favorite key..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), it will probably do what you want. I'm not highly versed in it myself, so can't help with the exact script unfortunately.